# Color loop produces (null) instead of colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, for-loop, uicolor

@BJ Homer was good enough to post this code a couple of years ago. It was actually written to populate an array with colors, but I modified it slightly to populate a core data store for the purpose of driving a `UICollectionView`. It seems to be doing that, but all my colors are null (black).

Here's the code:

```
+(void) loadColorsIntoCD
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

    int tag = 0;
    float INCREMENT = 0.0625;
    for (float hue = 0.0; hue < 1.0; hue += INCREMENT)
    {
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue
                                    saturation:1.0
                                    brightness:1.0
                                         alpha:1.0];

        [CatColor MR_createInContext:localContext];

        CatColor *thisColor;
        thisColor.color = color;
        thisColor.isTaken = NO;
        tag++;
        thisColor.idNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tag];
        NSLog(@"ThisColor.idNumber is %@",thisColor.idNumber);
        NSLog(@"ThisColor.color is %@",thisColor.color);
        [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    }
    NSLog(@"%i CatColors available", [CatColor MR_countOfEntities]);
}
```

Problem is, my NSLogs are reading:

```
ThisColor.idNumber is (null)
```

and

```
ThisColor.color is (null)
```

but then:

```
16 CatColors available
```

I'm really confused by this value which changes with each iteration through the loop, seeming to indicate that colors are being produced:

```
color   UIDeviceRGBColor *  0x8d83870   0x08d83870
```

Can someone please point out my mistake? I've been beating on this thing for the better part of a day.

Thanks for looking. All help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not assigning the created entity to your local variable. You should do this:

```
CatColor *thisColor = [CatColor MR_createInContext:localContext];
```

Comment: Perfect! Dumbo mistake on my part--just overlooked it and never saw it in subsequent reads. You'll get a green checkmark soon as the clock runs out. Thanks!